# How to navigate to a network drive when using Ubuntu via the Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: networking, mount, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed Ubuntu on my Windows 10 laptop via the [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10).

I have a NAS drive connected to my home Wi-Fi network. There's a "share" on it, accessible at `\\MYCLOUDEX2ULTRA\Home` that I've also mounted in Windows as my `Z:` drive.

When I start up the Ubuntu console, if I go to `/mnt/` I can see `c` and `d` directories there (for my laptop's local hard drives), but how can I navigate to my Z Drive?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked for me

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/mydesktopC
```

followed by

```
mount -t drvfs '\\mydesktop\C$' /mnt/mydesktopC
```

I used my C drive as a shared drive but I suppose you could do it for any share...

Comment: when I try the same `mount` command, I get `mount: only root can use "--types" option` and when I try it with sudo, I get `mount: /mnt/z: special device \\MYCLOUDEX2ULTRA\Home$ does not exist.`

Comment: C$ is a default administrative share on Windows (there is one for each local drive).
Is Home$ a shared folder you have defined yourself? Typically, I would not expect these shared folders to finish in $, other than the default administrative shares.
If you type \\MYCLOUDEX2ULTRA within Windows Explorer, it should show you the shared folders defined

Comment: OK sorry, I'm not a Unix or networking expert so I was just following your lead with the `$`. I tried again without the dollar symbol, and now get `mount: /mnt/z: can't find in /etc/fstab.` In /etc/fstab, there is just one line: `LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /        ext4   defaults        0 0`

Comment: I am not a Unix and/or network expert either! Welcome... I would try to use "sudo" in front of mount.
In my ubuntu machine, I have the same content as you in /etc/fstab